# Codeigniter - How to prevent user from accessing data by entering random ID or Code

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an issue regarding viewing of data. I'm working on some real estate project where there is a Code Page (to enter the code for House Status) and a Status Page (where details of house are displayed). Now, I can block the users from redirecting to Status Page on entering wrong code until they enter the correct one. What if the user tries to enter some random code in the URL of Status Page, then in case of wrong code, the page displays errors. How can I avoid this? And how can I just redirect the user back to Code Page in this case?

Updated:
I have used the condition on my View Page:

```
<body id="status-page">
<?php
     if($listing[0]['code'] != $listing_code){
        die();
     }else{ ?>
        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="page-loader-wrapper">
         ....
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Controller:

```
function index(){
    $listing_code = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $result = $this->status_model->get_listing($listing_code);
    $data['listing'] = $result;
    $data['listing_code'] = $listing_code;
}
```

Model:

```
function get_listing($listing_code){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->listings_table);
    $this->db->where('code',$listing_code);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;         
}
```

Everything's working fine except that when i change the url code for a wrong one then instead of terminating the Page, it displays errors....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different options 
1 ) Generate a hard code to guess , you can do that by using something like this

```
$code =  substr(md5(rand(16, time())), 0, 16);
```

In case the user types in a wrong code and it displace error
 use an if command to kill the rest of the page`if(condition to check if code exists ) {die();}`

2) Or create a login and create a table listing the people who can use the code

Comment: Where do I use the condition? In the controller or View? Can you tell the condition exactly, I didn't understand

Comment: Okay if the variable for the existing code is $code and the code the user typed in is $input

Comment: you write `if($code != input){die();} else{//whatever that needs to happen}`

Comment: i get that but where do I put the condition?

Comment: View cause that's what you want to show to the user right ? though I dont have experience with codeigniter

Comment: So the code starts in the controller so you should add it in the controller , you should start before using $listing_code to get data